# Calculate a rolling sum of 3 month in R data frame based on a date column and Product

Tags: r

I am looking to calculate a 3 month rolling sum of values in one column of a data frame based upon the dates in another column and product.

newResults data frame columns :  Product, Date, Value

In this example, I wish to calculate the rolling sum of value for Product for 3 months. I have sorted the data frame on Product and Date.

Dataset Example:

[Sample Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA3vV.png)

My Code:

```
newResults = newResults %>%
  group_by(Product) %>%
  mutate(Roll_12Mth =
           rollapplyr(Value, width = 1:n() - findInterval( Date %m-% months(3), date), sum)) %>%
ungroup
```

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Roll_12Mth`.
x could not find function "%m-%"
i Input `Roll_12Mth` is `rollapplyr(...)`.

Output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFJFf.png)

Comment: No one except you can run this since the library statements are missing and the input is only given as an image so would have to be retyped.  Please read the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page. The code seems to be missing a library statement to load the lubridate package which is where %m-% is found.

Answer (score 0):

If the dates are always spaced 1 month apart, it is easy.

```
dat=data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("2/1/2017", "%m/%d/%Y"), as.Date("1/1/2018", "%m/%d/%Y"), by="month"),
Product=rep(c("A", "B"), each=6),
Value=c(4182, 4822, 4805, 6235, 3665, 3326, 3486, 3379, 3596, 3954, 3745, 3956))
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(Product) %>%
  arrange(Date, .by_group=TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Value=rollapplyr(Value, 3, sum, partial=TRUE))

   Date       Product Value
   <date>     <fct>   <dbl>
 1 2017-02-01 A        4182
 2 2017-03-01 A        9004
 3 2017-04-01 A       13809
 4 2017-05-01 A       15862
 5 2017-06-01 A       14705
 6 2017-07-01 A       13226
 7 2017-08-01 B        3486
 8 2017-09-01 B        6865
 9 2017-10-01 B       10461
10 2017-11-01 B       10929
11 2017-12-01 B       11295
12 2018-01-01 B       11655
```